# Why don't I get problem highlighting for C++ in VS Code if I write invalid code in an unused template function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

My VS Code's C/C++ extension can crawl errors inside my `main()` function, but not in my template function.

Showing the problem highlighting here in my main function:
[image: screenshot of main function with problem highlighting]

But not here in my template function definition where I created the same problem of assigning a string literal to an int:
[image: screenshot of template function with no problem highlighting]

Why does this happen?

I tried to search Extension settings but found nothing (I may have skipped something).

Here's some code you can use to reproduce the behaviour:

```cpp
template <typename T>
int foo() {
    int num = "hello world!"; // error here
    return num;
}
int main() {
    return foo<int>(); // use the template
}
```

```cpp
template <typename T>
int foo() {
    int num = "hello world!"; // no error here
    return num;
}
int main() {
    return 0; // do not use the template
}
```

Comment: The problem may be caused because you use a template for `Node`. Check if the errors in a function or a class without template are underlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem detection in VS Code's Microsoft C++ extension is based on compiler diagnostics. Compilers are not required to emit diagnostics for problems that occur in uninstantiated templates. No compiler diagnostic -> no problem indicator from the C++ extension.

If you really want the problem indicator and you never implicitly instantiate the template by using it, I suppose you could [explicitly instantiate it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation).

See also this Q&A: [error in unused template method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17598699/11107541).